# Can't seperate names and dates from a dictionary in order to write them in an excel file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, web-scraping, openpyxl

I've created a script in python to parse the business names and their dates from a webpage and write them to an excel file using openpyxl. My intention is to place the names and dates in seperate columns like `name1 date1 name2 date2` and so on.

My current attempt can fetch the content in a dictionary and produces the result like below:

```
{'NATIONAL OPERA STUDIO': '18 Nov 2010', 'NATIONAL THEATRE BALLET SCHOOL': '12 Aug 2005', 'NATIONAL THEATRE DRAMA SCHOOL': '12 Aug 2005', 'NATIONAL THEATRE': '30 Mar 2000'}
```

***How can I place the names and dates in an excel file like following?***

```
column1                 column2       column3                           column4  
NATIONAL OPERA STUDIO   18 Nov 2010   NATIONAL THEATRE BALLET SCHOOL    12 Aug 2005
```

This is my try so far:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('container.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

url = "https://abr.business.gov.au/ABN/View?id=78007306283"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
try:
    names_n_dates = {item.find("a").get_text(strip=True):' '.join(item.find("a").find_parent().find_next_sibling().text.split()) for item in soup.find("th",text=re.compile("Business name",re.I)).find_parent().find_next_siblings("tr")}
except AttributeError: names_n_dates = ""

items = {k:v for k,v in names_n_dates.items()}
print(items)

ws.append([items.split()])
wb.save("container.xlsx")
```

I know I can't apply split function on dictionary but I don't know any alternative option eiter to achieve the same. I used ***ws.append([])*** to include the fields in an excel file and I wish to keep this command as it is because there are other fields to include within it later.

Comment: You should really split up the list comprehension, it's way to long to be understood easily.

Comment: `ws.append(items.values())` Though you probably want sort it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep `ws.append()` as you appear to intend (appending one list as one row), then do this:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('container.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

url = "https://abr.business.gov.au/ABN/View?id=78007306283"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
try:
    names_n_dates = {item.find("a").get_text(strip=True):' '.join(item.find("a").find_parent().find_next_sibling().text.split()) for item in soup.find("th",text=re.compile("Business name",re.I)).find_parent().find_next_siblings("tr")}
except AttributeError: names_n_dates = ""

row = []

for item in names_n_dates.items():
   for column in item:
       row.append(column)

ws.append(row)

wb.save("container.xlsx")
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I was trying to achieve @Logan Bertram. A minor twitch in your script will satisfy my requirement. That said, how can I use `ws.append([row])` instead of `ws.append(row)`? Thanks.

Comment: Do you intend to append a list of lists that look like `row` (`ws.append([row, row2, row3])`)?

Comment: Yes, it is. However, I've sorted that out using `+` operator. Btw, you might wanna change your script to reflect this `items = [column for item in names_n_dates.items() for column in item]
ws.append(items)`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you can iterate over the dictionary items that are tuples of (key, value), and then get the key and value of each one of those items like a list. The key is in position 0 of the item and value is in position 1.

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('container.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

url = "https://abr.business.gov.au/ABN/View?id=78007306283"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
try:
    names_n_dates = {item.find("a").get_text(strip=True):' '.join(item.find("a").find_parent().find_next_sibling().text.split()) for item in soup.find("th",text=re.compile("Business name",re.I)).find_parent().find_next_siblings("tr")}
except AttributeError: names_n_dates = ""

row = []

for item in dict.items(): #iterate over all dict items
   row.append(item[0]) #key
   row.append(item[1]) #value

ws.append(row)

wb.save("container.xlsx")
```

Comment: Each item you append is its own row, so this will just produce a worksheet with one column instead of one row.